# Authenticate mobile app user connecting to SharePoint 2013 with Form Based Authentication (FBA)

Tags: react-native, sharepoint, xamarin.forms, sharepoint-2013, fba

We have a SharePoint 2013 Farm, and we are switching from Windows Authentication to Form Based Authentication (FBA).
We have a mobile app connecting to SharePoint using Windows Authentication.
How could I use FBA instead?
Currently the mobile app is using Xamarin Forms but we'll use React Native later on.
Not sure if there is a way to do it using .net or javascript.

Comment: A quick search gave me this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/step-by-step-fba-authentication) maybe it helps

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is a very good article how to set up FBA, but I am looking for something else, which is authenticating by code the user of an external application on a SharePoint site using FBA. I have found this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/build-mobile-apps-for-other-platforms-using-sharepoint) which provides a C# example.